# how to enable or disable asp.net validators in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

i just want to enable/disable the validatos don't want to fire them. waiting for reply.thanks in advance.

ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById("")); this function enable the validator and perform validation... i don't want the validation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById("ValidatorControlID"), false);
```

to disable validator.